# Posting a message to User's walls as application using Facebook PHP registration API?

Tags: php, api

i am using facebook registration API,and i want to post a message on user's wall,but since Feb. 2013 we can not post to other people’s walls any more via API. So plzz help me to find the correct code..

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=<?php echo $redirect_uri;?>&
         scope=publish_stream,offline_access&fields=[
                {'name':'name'}, 
                {'name':'first_name'},
                {'name':'last_name'}, 
                {'name':'email'},
                {'name':'gender'},
                {'name':'birthday'},
                {'name':'password'}
                ]"scrolling="auto"frameborder="no"style="border:none"allowTransparency="true"width="570"height="800">
            </iframe>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: *Offtopic* If someone says "plz" because it's shorter than "please", I'd like to say "no" because it's shorter than "yes"...

Comment: there were some API changes https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/ especially "Curly bracket syntax for mentioning users in notifications going away" and "Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using iframe?? it use withing facebook .You dont need to use this. just write php code for publish. thanx

```
if(isset($_POST['mapp_message'])){
    try {
        $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
            'message' => $_POST['mapp_message']
        ));
        $sent = true;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

     error_log($e);
$user = null;
        //do something about it
    }
}
```

this is my code and its working fine on my wall

Comment: replace me to friend id .. thanx advance :)

Answer (score 0):

basically we are using facebook registration API for our website user registration and we are storing user data in our database with access token, at the time of registration,we want the user allow us the wall post permission.So what we will do..?